# How do Vampire Rogues commit a break-in robbery without an invitation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How do Vampire Rogues commit a robbery without an invitation to get into the place they are breaking into?

Comment: Could you clarify the actual scenario you're planning on going into? What and where are you robbing? "How can they break into places" is too open-ended for us to manage proper solutions to -- if you give us only a sentence, we can only give you approximately one back, and we're not interested in gathering answers like that. Right now this looks like it'll just attract arbitrary brainstorming ideas (not a single best or correct plan for a specific robbery) which means it's not workable in this format.

Answer (score 3):

The best way for a Vampire to avoid the issue of entering a dwelling would be to break into businesses, or some other sort of public space, rather than a home.

Answer (score 1):

The vampire rogue can easily dress up as a bard with a disguise, and offer to perform for the family. Especially if they were rich. Traveling bards were known for performing for high class families. It would be easy for a bard to get invited in. then since they have the invitation, they can go in anytime they please. Say the middle of the night. The family would be asleep.

It would also depend on what was being stolen. If they're just after gold, or gems, start a small fire outside of the home. Then attack and kill the people as they run outside in their sleeping clothes. No owner, no master of the dwelling. Then you're free to do as you please. If it is something burnable, use magic or something of the sort to smash a hole in the wall then hide. They'll come out at least to investigate. Then proceed to kill them as usual again. Just because its a break in robbery does not mean you have to be secretive. It all depends on location of the dwelling, what you're trying to rob them of. There's many different ways of completing this.

Comment: That's a good one

Comment: I really wanted to say dress up as a magic wand repairman, but the thought seemed a bit unhelpful.

Comment: Do you have any experience suggesting that this approach works? How did it go when you tried it at your table?

Comment: Also, is this actually canonical or something that you/your GM plays?

Comment: My GM has played it a few times. If the vamp rolls high enough on rolls for speech it works out fine. Otherwise the vamp gets told to go kick rocks because they "don't need another bard performing."